# CompareTo Not Resulting in Expected Sort Order

Tags: c#, .net, compareto

Trying to sort a list of these:

```
public class BusinessEvents : IComparable<BusinessEvent>
{
    public long VersionId {get;set;}
    public EventType EventType {get;set;}
}
```

Here's the sort logic:

```
public int CompareTo(BusinessEvent businessEvent)
{
    if (VersionId > businessEvent.VersionId)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (VersionId < businessEvent.VersionId)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (EventType == EventType.TypeC ||
        EventType == EventType.TypeD ||
        EventType == EventType.TypeE)
    {
        if (businessEvent.EventType == EventType.TypeA ||
            businessEvent.EventType == EventType.TypeB)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, this unit test is failing:

```
[Test]
public void BusinessEvent_Sort_Correctly_Break_Ties_Multiple()
{
    // arrange
    var event1 = GetEventWithTypeAndVersionId(1, EventType.TypeA);
    var event2 = GetEventWithTypeAndVersionId(1, EventType.TypeD);
    var event3 = GetEventWithTypeAndVersionId(1, EventType.TypeC);
    var event4 = GetEventWithTypeAndVersionId(2, EventType.TypeB);
    var event5 = GetEventWithTypeAndVersionId(2, EventType.TypeE);
    var event6 = GetEventWithTypeAndVersionId(2, EventType.TypeC);
    var events = new List<BusinessEvent> {event4, event2, event5, event6, event3, event1};

    // act
    events = events.OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
        
    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(EventType.TypeA, events[0].EventType);
    Assert.AreEqual(EventType.TypeD, events[1].EventType);
    Assert.AreEqual(EventType.TypeC, events[2].EventType);
    Assert.AreEqual(EventType.TypeB, events[3].EventType);
    Assert.AreEqual(EventType.TypeE, events[4].EventType);
    Assert.AreEqual(EventType.TypeC, events[5].EventType);
}
```

It's failing on the very first assert. It's putting `EventType.TypeD` with `VersionId` of 1 first in the sorted list, even though I'm specifying `EventType.TypeD` comes after `EventType.TypeA` when the `VersionId` matches.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something of what this API provides. How can I get my expected result?

Comment: `events.OrderBy(c => c).ToList()` change nothing in the order ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The order is changing, it just doesn't appear to be the correct order based on my understanding of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is that you are not also returning `-1` in cases when `this.EventType` is `TypeA` or `TypeB`, you return `0` in that case.**

You can also simplify this by using `int.CompareTo` to deal with the various cases. The best way to implement custom compare logic is to use standard `CompareTo` on each level and check for `!= 0`.

```cs
public int CompareTo(BusinessEvent businessEvent)
{
    var cmp = VersionId.CompareTo(businessEvent.VersionId);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    cmp = (EventType == EventType.TypeA || EventType == EventType.TypeB ? 0 : 1)
        .CompareTo(
            businessEvent.EventType == EventType.TypeA ||
            businessEvent.EventType == EventType.TypeB ? 0 : 1);

    return cmp;
}
```

The way this works is that it transforms `TypeA` and `TypeB` to `0` and everything else to `1`, then it compares that. Obviously `0` sorts before `1`.

You can add further conditions or sorts by writing some kind of transform function that merges different `EventType` together.

Comment: Thank you, this works but I'm not too clear on why. I guess I need to look into how exactly the logic making the CompareTo call handles responses of -1/0/1

Comment: Have added explanation. It's not `CompareTo` that is doing it per se, it is the ternary `? 0 : 1`